# Sum matrix Racket

Tags: matrix, racket

I'm trying to do a function in Racket that sum 2 matrix, using map and apply, the problem is that I only used map like this

`(define (sumM x y)
   (map(lambda (x y) (map + x y)) x y))
      (sumM '((10 10 10) (5 5 5)) '((1 1 1) (2 2 2)))`

Which it gives me: `(sumM '((10 10 10) (5 5 5)) '((1 1 1) (2 2 2))) ->'((11 11 11) (7 7 7))`

but the thing is: I want just the result, something like 54
¿How can I use the apply to get the 54 and not the result matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
(define (sumM x y)
  (+ (apply + (map (lambda (sl) (apply + sl)) x))
     (apply + (map (lambda (sl) (apply + sl)) y))))
```

It works for lists of lists of arbitrary length, finding the total sum of all its elements. For example:

```
(sumM '((10 10 10) (5 5 5)) '((1 1 1) (2 2 2)))
=> 54
```